# How to fix a 3x3 block of images with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a 3x3 block of images.

I want the images to be 400px wide and 300px in height.

I also want the images to stretch from edge to edge of the screen and for there to be no space between the images.

[This is what it looks like at the moment](http://ec2-52-211-25-124.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/what-we-do/)

This is my current CSS and HTML:

```css
.clear {
  clear: both;
}

#grid {
  width: 100%;
}

.grid-element {
  width: 33.3333%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">

  <div class="grid-element">
    <img src="http://static.caloriecount.about.com/images/medium/colby-cheese-157898.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="grid-element">
    <img src="http://static.caloriecount.about.com/images/medium/colby-cheese-157898.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="grid-element">
    <img src="http://static.caloriecount.about.com/images/medium/colby-cheese-157898.jpg" />
  </div>


  <div class="grid-element">
    <img src="http://static.caloriecount.about.com/images/medium/colby-cheese-157898.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="grid-element">
    <img src="http://static.caloriecount.about.com/images/medium/colby-cheese-157898.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="grid-element">
    <img src="http://static.caloriecount.about.com/images/medium/colby-cheese-157898.jpg" />
  </div>


  <div class="grid-element">
    <img src="http://static.caloriecount.about.com/images/medium/colby-cheese-157898.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="grid-element">
    <img src="http://static.caloriecount.about.com/images/medium/colby-cheese-157898.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="grid-element">
    <img src="http://static.caloriecount.about.com/images/medium/colby-cheese-157898.jpg" />
  </div>

</div>

<div class="clear">Example taken from <a href="https://gist.github.com/grandoch/1400971">grandoch</a>'s gist</div>
```

Comment: If you want it to stretch to the edges of your screen, the width of #grid should be 100% rather than 600px, and width of each of your columns should be 33.33%.

Comment: I have implemented those changes and it makes very little diference. I have also added new larger images.

Comment: check this link:-https://css-tricks.com/equidistant-objects-with-css/

Comment: why not using flexbox?

Comment: @fefe If the only thing he wants to do is have the images be a third of the width of whatever, then is there any reason to use something with worse browser support than percentage dimensions?

Comment: I think the problem is a container outside of the above html/css. But I cant work out which one: - http://ec2-52-211-25-124.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/what-we-do/

Comment: @Roope http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: @fefe Yes? That's just proving my point.

Comment: that 99% of available browser supports flexbox? even bootstrap 4 will include flexbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E. Updated the answer for use with Bootstrap.

Bootstrap adds left and right padding for all `col-*-*` elements, so you will merely need to remove that padding.

For full viewport width, you will need to use a fluid container, i.e. the `container-fluid` class.

```css
#grid .grid-element {
  height: 200px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="grid" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 grid-element">
      <img src="http://static.caloriecount.about.com/images/medium/colby-cheese-157898.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4  grid-element">
      <img src="http://static.caloriecount.about.com/images/medium/colby-cheese-157898.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4  grid-element">
      <img src="http://static.caloriecount.about.com/images/medium/colby-cheese-157898.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4  grid-element">
      <img src="http://static.caloriecount.about.com/images/medium/colby-cheese-157898.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4  grid-element">
      <img src="http://static.caloriecount.about.com/images/medium/colby-cheese-157898.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4  grid-element">
      <img src="http://static.caloriecount.about.com/images/medium/colby-cheese-157898.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4  grid-element">
      <img src="http://static.caloriecount.about.com/images/medium/colby-cheese-157898.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4  grid-element">
      <img src="http://static.caloriecount.about.com/images/medium/colby-cheese-157898.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4  grid-element">
      <img src="http://static.caloriecount.about.com/images/medium/colby-cheese-157898.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This s slightly better. However, note how it appears on the actual site now

Comment: You need to make an example that replicates your problem. Don't make an unrelated example and then refer to an external site when the given solution does not directly apply with some framework you do not mention. I will update my answer to support Bootstrap.

Comment: @GavinReynoldson See the updated answer. You will only need to remove the padding, if you're setting the width with columns anyway.

Comment: Thanks @roope. It now looks awesome. However, I still cant get the row to stretch from one side of the screen to the other.

Comment: @GavinReynoldson Use the `container-fluid` class.